# How to get rid of foreign key property in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I use EF CTP 5 Code First. If you ask EF to generate database for the model like this it will create appropriate foreign key relationship for you:

```
public class Parent
{
    public ICollection<Child> MyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{ 
    public Parent MyParent { get; set; }
}
```

Child table gonna have something like MyParent_Id field as a result of such generation. Now I'm having reverse problem - I have a Db schema which I have to build similar simple model for. By similar simple I mean without any explicit foreign key properties. Is any way to do it?

The only way to do the mapping I found looks like this, but it implies having public property MyParentId in the model which I'm trying to avoid. So how to avoid it?

```
public class Child 
{ 
    [Column("ParentID")]
    public int MyParentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MyParentId")]
    public Parent MyParent { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 3 versions were released since CTP5 so you should immediately upgrade to [Entity Framework 4.1 Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825)

Comment: Ladislav, Good news. I'll do update. Thanks for this info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define your mapping in code rather than using attributes. In your "context" class (the one that derives from `DbContext`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.MyParent)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("MyParent_Id"));
}
```

In this case, "MyParent_Id" is the name of the column in the child table rather than the name of any property on the `Child` class.

Comment: It works! I thought attributes can do the same thing, but looks like EF fluent configuration is the only way to set the relationship up properly. Thanks.